# vmWare Player - virtual machine configured for 2 CPUs but I only have 1 CPU

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-player, multi-core

I copied a virtual machine that I downloaded but can't play it in vmWare player.
When I start to play it, it says:

> This virtual machine is configured to run with 2 CPUs, but the host
>   has only 1 CPU. This virtual machine cannot be powered on.

Is there any way how to solve this problem?
Other than buying a processor that has 2 cores?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can reconfigure the virtual machine for a single CPU.

The easiest way to do this is to [download vmware workstation](http://www.vmware.com/go/downloadworkstation). It will give you a 30 day trial, which should be more than enough to reconfigure your downloaded VMs.

You did not state which OS was installed inside the VM. If that is windows then it might have problems (e.g. it might want to reactivate).

Comment: This is right, and @Einsteins Grandson should check and evaluate if  is recommended run that Machine/Apliance with only 1 core, considering if you are trying to run that with only 1 core that means mby your host is a bit out to date..

Answer (score 3):

You can simply edit the VMX file defining the VM settings with a common text editor.

I don't know the exact entry name but search for en entry related to cpu or core you is set to "2". May be it is the entry "sched.cpu.min".

Change the value to "1", save it and try to start the VM. If it works you got it - if not undo the changes and try the next entry.

Comment: I just started vmware workstation version 8 and changed the number of CPUs from 2 to 1 on one of my VMs. In the config file (.vmx) the value of numvcpus = "2" changed to numvcpus = "1".

Answer (score -1):

You can change it to 1. Go in to virtual machine settings and then change the number of processors to 1. That should fix it.